# Get line number where variable is defined

Tags: python, debugging, inspect

I'm trying to extract the line number where a specific variable was created.  This sounds like a simple question, after all, I could loop through the lines of code and try to search, or do a regular expression.  But that might be a false line number and I would prefer, if possible, to parse the Python code as-is and get a real line number.

Here's what I have:

```
class MyClass:

    """
    MyClass.

    Notice that we do override the name class attribute.

    class MyClass:

        name = "a real name"

    """

    name = "the true name"

    def __iinit__(self):
        pass
```

Thanks to `inspect.getsourcelines`, I can get the lines of the class (more than one class might be defined in a file and they might all have a different `name` attribute).  What I need from this is to find the line number where the `name` class attribute was defined for this class.  Use `ast`?  `dis`?  I'm not against any suggestion.

> This is useful for debugging.  The class attribute in my case is a multi-line string containing some formatted text and I need to report the error with file name and line number when problems occur.  So I would rather know where the attribute is defined, not just have its value.

Thanks for your help,

### Edit

Based on @bsbueno 's answer, I tried to come up with something simple that didn't disturb my original design, flowed as it probably is.  I'm creating a simple metaclass whose sole job is to register this attribute.  Notice that I'm still "wrapping" the attribute in a function call in the `Child` class, so this solution isn't ideal and it's not much better than defining the `register` function in a separate namespace.  All in all, what I've done is not the best option, but it provides another example and might be useful for others, or so I hope:

```
import sys

class MetaRegister(type):

    def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwds):
        return {"register": MetaRegister.register}

    @staticmethod
    def register(value):
        frame = sys._getframe().f_back
        file = frame.f_globals["__file__"]
        line = frame.f_lineno
        print(f"Calling register {file}:{line}: {value!r}")
        return value

class Parent(metaclass=MetaRegister):

    option = None

class Child(Parent):

    option = register(3)
```

The metaclass' `__prepare__` method is called before the other classes (both `Parent` and `Child`) are created.  It adds something in their namespace (in this case, the `register` function).  This is used directly in the `Child`'s class body.  The `register` function (which is actually a static method on the metaclass itself) doesn't do much but printing where it was first called.  This is enough for me, though as I've said, it's a solution that could feel like it's not solving much.  Open opinion!

Comment: `__iinit__` ?  double `i`?

Comment: I would guess that's a mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While for functions and global variables this would be more or less straightforward. tough weird, using "dis", for class attributes this might be a lot more convoluted - as class bodies are first compiled to a code object, that is run once when the class is defined, and all but "thrown away" once the class is properly created.

At that point you have only the class'`__dict__` with no hints of order of creation or place of creation at all.

Also, using `dis` will make it possible to find where variables are attributed by searching the `STORE_NAME` opcode, you have the same problem of not knowing *which* of those was run - but it would be no more reliable than a textual search for patterns on the source code itself.

The only reliable way of doing this is, if instead of using regular variables, you use special descriptors - those could inspect the place where the call to set their values was made, and annotate that in a registry.

So, all you'd need is that the variables you want to trace live inside a special object, which can have a short name - the final code would look like this:

```
from variable_registry import R

class MyClass:

   R.name = "the true name"

   def __init__(self):
        print(R.name)
```

This would need special handling if you need instance variables - but it still could be done by a more convoluted mechanism. For class and global variables you'd be good as for local variables in a non-concurrent execution.

```
import sys

class Registry:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__["_registry"] = {}

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        frame = sys._getframe().f_back
        file = frame.f_globals["__file__"]
        self.__dict__["_registry"][name] = file, frame.f_lineno, value
        super().__setattr__(name, value)


R = Registry()
```

Comment: Thanks, this does sound like a good solution I hadn't considered.  I'm not against wrapping the str in an attribute definition.  I wasn't aware this syntax was even possible.  Well, live and learn!

Answer (score 1):

```py
from inspect import currentframe

def get_linenumber():
    cf = currentframe()
    return cf.f_back.f_lineno
```